# Is Root domain CNAME to other domain allowed by DNS RFC?

Tags: dns, cname

We are hosting the page of many of our customers.  We want to be able to provide our customers with a subdomain of our own domain like customerpages.ourdomain.com so they can create a CNAME to this subdomain.

```
www.customer1.com CNAME customerpages.ourdomain.com.  {This will work just fine.}
```

But the situation is I don't know if all our customers will be able to place the following CNAME

```
customer1.com CNAME customerpages.ourdomain.com
```

This last CNAME looks like it's against the RFC of DNS.

Any thoughts will be appreciated.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No, you can't do that - `CNAME` records can only exist as single records and not combined with any other resource record (DNSSEC records excepted).

There are explicit `SOA` and `NS` records always present at the top of each domain, so that prevents the use of the `CNAME` at the same part of the hierarchy.

Comment: Can you say anything as to why a SOA and NS prevents a CNAME? Seriously, I don't understand. Is this some god-given limitation or is there some technical ambiguity preventing a CNAME at the same level as a SOA and NS from functioning?

Comment: @Sven see §3.6.2 of RFC 1034.

Comment: @Sven The problem is that RFC1034 predates [RFC2119](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2119.txt) and the phrasing "no other data *should* be
present" is used, which leaves it open to interpretation. §6.1 and §10.1 of RFC2181 make the rules more explicit [when interpreted together](http://serverfault.com/a/613830/152073).

Comment: For those interested in a more thoroughly detailed article, Cloudflare has a great [blog post](https://blog.cloudflare.com/introducing-cname-flattening-rfc-compliant-cnames-at-a-domains-root/) on this in which they explain how they apply `CNAME Flattening` to work around this. TLDR: Quote: "Technically, the root could be a CNAME but the RFCs state that once a record has a CNAME it can't have any other entries associated with it"

Answer (score 2):

It's true, given a domain example.com, some DNS servers (tinydns for one) won't complain if you set up CNAME records for both example.com and [www.example.com](http://www.example.com). But still I'd avoid it as it would break e-mail for example.com (see RFC 2821 "[Address Resolution and Mail Handling](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2821#section-5)").