# web.config code to redirect www to non www

Tags: regex, azure

I have an azure website that when users visit I want to redirect them to the non www version via my web.config file

so if visitors type in `www.example.com`it will redirect them to `example.com` instead.

I wrote this regular expression to try to match this

```
www\/(.*).com\/(.*)
```

But it doesn't seem to work on Regexpal. I'm not sure if I'm just not using the site correctly.

How would I achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows Azure: How to 301 non-www url to www for a domain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6747007/windows-azure-how-to-301-non-www-url-to-www-for-a-domain)

Comment: Do you need to check anything after `www.`, like ensuring it is a `.com` site?