# Question on CNAME for different domains

Tags: dns, virtualhost, cname

Is it posssible for me to use CNAME for different domains like

www.domain2.com CNAME www.domain1.com

Both are server from same server but different Virtual host (root paths are different)

Answer (score 15):

Yes, it is valid for a CNAME to point to an entirely different domain. This is often used in the context of using CNAME records to handle the TLD variants on your domain such as:

```
mydomain.com CNAME mydomain.net.
```

Comment: You should not CNAME whole domain, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/757972/196206 or http://serverfault.com/q/430970/80856

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do this at the DNS level, but that effectively means that both domains point to the same resource. If you have 2 different applications serving different content, than this is not the case.