# CNAME record not working with Wordpress website

Tags: php, wordpress, cname

I need to load my Wordpress website under a different domain apart from my primary domain using a CNAME record. Both domains are belonging to me. I should mention that since some people using this feature as a phishing tool. I added a CNAME record into my second domain's configurations. But site is not loading as expected. It's redirecting to the primary domain as A record does instead of serving the site under the second domain. Following is the sample of my CNAME record. I can't share the exact details any of the websites.

### CNAME record

```
Name: www.secondarydomain.com
Type: CNAME
Value: primarydomain.com
TTL: 5 minutes
```

Comment: Please check out this https://www.zoho.com/mail/help/adminconsole/wordpress.html it may be helpful for you

Comment: Thanks, but already did that. And my DNS manager is not with Wordpress. It's separate.

Comment: Technically you shouldn't do this.  You are better to create a CNAME on the primary domain called blog.primarydomain.com, for example, and do a 302 redirect from here.

Here is an explanation on why not.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/656009/how-to-overcome-root-domain-cname-restrictions/757972#757972

Comment: @cherrysoft : sorry i updated my question. It should be www subdomain. Not an apex/naked domain.

Comment: Try adding a period at end of domain!

Comment: @cherrysoft : You mean for the Name record or for the value record?

Comment: Both domains have added period symbol at the end