# Configure DNS to work with both heroku and google suite

Tags: heroku, dns

I currently have 3 DNS records:

```
www.erbij.app - CNAME - www.erbij.app.herokudns.com
api.erbij.app - CNAME - api.erbij.app.herokudns.com
erbij.app - CNAME - erbij.app.herokudns.com
```

Our web app and api are functioning fine. However, I'd like to have our email hosted by Google Suite, so I'm trying to add MX records:

```
erbij.app - MX - ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
```

But I get an error that I can't have two records for erbij.app.
I've tried contacting my domain registrar, but they don't have a blue.

In [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/656009/how-to-overcome-root-domain-cname-restrictions) the possible solution of subdomain redirection is mentioned, but how does this work? If erbij.app is not pointing to a server, how can I use server software to redirect all requests to www.erbij.app?

My apologies if this is a silly question. I know very little about DNS records.

Comment: Who is managing your DNS? Your domain registrar? If so, which one? Also, if you aren't I'd recommend using a third-party DNS provider like Cloudflare as the records you are creating should work fine,

Comment: Yes, my domain registrar. How do I use a third-party DNS provider with my current domain registrar? Do I change my nameservers?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up signing up for CloudFlare (thanks Luke Ramsden for the tip) to manage my DNS. Cloudflare does allow users to add CNAME/ALIAS records to the root domain.

Simply change the nameservers in the control panel of your registrar, configure the domain on cloudflare.com and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Is you zone `erbij.app`? In that case you shouldn't have a CNAME record that has the same name as your zone in the first place, and also, a CNAME record name must be unique so you cannot have an MX with that name if you have the CNAME

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you have a proposed solution?

Comment: Is `erbij.app` your root zone?

Comment: What you really should be doing to have that MX record is removing the ```erbij.app IN CNAME erbij.app.herokudns.com```, and either making an A/AAAA that points to your app service, a load balancer, or a service that forwards traffic to the desired destination

Comment: the problem is that erbij.app.herokudns.com does not have a static IP, that's why we're using CNAME