# Map AWS S3 bucket to no subdomain (no www, nothing)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dns, cname

Wondering how would I achieve such configuration on my DNS records. I have created a bucket named 'myowndomain.com' and set it as a static web hosting that redirects to 'www.myowndomain.com'. After that I have created a CNAME:

@   CNAME   myowndomain.com.s3-website-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com.

But it does not work. Oh, it has been more than 24 hours that I have created it, so it should be spread already...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Route53 for DNS, create a ALIAS record pointing your zone apex to your S3 static website. If necessary, also create a bucket for the "with www" version or keep links with bucket redirection rules.

See:
http://nathangrigg.net/2013/02/s3-redirects-again/

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's against the DNS RFC to allow a CNAME at the root level of your dns record. Your dns provider may provide a way for you to do this, if not, another option is to use [wwwizer](http://wwwizer.com/naked-domain-redirect).

See [Is Root domain CNAME to other domain allowed by DNS RFC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/655235/is-root-domain-cname-to-other-domain-allowed-by-dns-rfc) for more info.